# Set int var value as wildcard

Tags: sql

I've looked into this and I'm just struggling to accept that it isn't possible to do.

I write queries for others to use and normally include some declared variables at the top so the user can "filter" their search at the top of the query and not bother with the rest.

Sometimes the user may not want to specify the values for a particular variable, as they want to return all types. I know this isn't what SQL is for and that there are reporting tools. Any suggestions on how to do this?

```
DECLARE @foo int, @bar bit
SET @foo = *
SET @bar = *

SELECT *
FROM table

WHERE foo = @foo
AND bar = @bar
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't use T-SQL. Only use tags relevant to what you are actually using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*` isn't a valid `int` value and even *if* an `int` value could be used as a wildcard, you would need to use `LIKE` not `=`.

What you want here is a `NULL` value and the proper boolean logic.

```sql
SELECT {Columns}
FROM [Table]
WHERE (foo = @foo OR @foo IS NULL)
  AND (bar = @bar OR @bar IS NULL)
OPTION (RECOMPILE);-- Comment out/remove if you aren't using T-sQL due to incorrect tagging
```

Comment: Perfect, the key was that logic. I had been trying to use 'Exists' with no success. The * was for illustrative purposes, I'd been trying forms of ```like``` and %, but thought that would be clearer for the explanation. The "or @var is null" is perfect. Many thanks.